# I'm getting an error "PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001FFA78D10E0>" when converting bytes to img

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, base64, image-conversion, merging-data

I am attempting to merge 2-byte arrays together and convert the bytes all together back into an image. However, I keep getting the issue "open raise UnidentifiedImageError( PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001FFA78D10E0>"

```py
from email.mime import base
import io
import base64
from PIL import Image
from numpy import byte
from array import array


compressedIm = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Student\Documents\Disso\Compressed_gabieureka.jpg")
compressedIm_resize = compressedIm.resize((500, 500))
buf = io.BytesIO()
compressedIm_resize.save(buf, format='JPEG')
byte_compressedIm = buf.getvalue()

Im2 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Student\Documents\Disso\Photos\votetemi.jpg")
Im2_resize = Im2.resize((500, 500))
buf2 = io.BytesIO()
Im2_resize.save(buf2, format='JPEG')
byte_Im2 = buf2.getvalue()

bytearray1 = bytearray(byte_compressedIm)
bytearray2 = bytearray(byte_Im2)
mergedBytearray = bytearray1 + bytearray2

b = base64.b64decode(mergedBytearray)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
image.show()
image.save("TheirDate", "PNG")
```

Does anyone have a solution or can spot a glaring error in my code?

Comment: Why do you Base64 decode your combined image? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: i saw it as a solution online, it seemed to function pretty well but it gave me that error after. Although the issue was with the line after so it could be a problem